# Restarts specific services across 8 servers

Tags: powershell

I created this script to stop and then start specific services across an environment of 8 servers.  The server names are Apollo-1 thru Apollo-8.  I'm looking for suggested changes to make sure my script is acceptable for production.

```
#Create a credential to be used on remote machines
$User = "MyDomain\myusername"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -asplaintext -force
$Credential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 
-ArgumentList $User, $Password


$Server1 = New-Object System.Object
$Server1 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value "Apollo-1"
$arrServ1Services = @("MSSQLSERVER","QueueManager")
$Server1 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Services -value $arrServ1Services



$Server2 = New-Object System.Object
$Server2 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value "Apollo-2"
$arrServ2Services = @("Analytics Engine", "MSSQLSERVER")
$Server2 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Services -value $arrServ2Services



$Server3 = New-Object System.Object
$Server3 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value "Apollo-3"
$arrServ3Services = @("EDDS Agent Manager", "MSSQLSERVER", "Secret Store") 
$Server3 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Services -value 
$arrServ3Services


$Server4 = New-Object System.Object
$Server4 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value "Apollo-4"
$arrServ4Services = @("Service Host Manager", "MSSQLSERVER","Service Bus 
Gateway","Service Bus Message Broker","Service Bus Resource 
Provider","Service Bus VSS","EDDS Agent Manager","Analytics Engine") 
$Server4 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Services -value arrServ4Services


$Server5 = New-Object System.Object
$Server5 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value "Apollo-5"
$arrServ5Services = @("MSSQLSERVER")
$Server5 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Services -value $arrServ5Services


$Server6 = New-Object System.Object
$Server6 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value "Apollo-6"
$arrServ6Services = @("Web Processing Manager", "Service Host Manager") 
$Server6 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Services -value $arrServ6Services


$Server7 = New-Object System.Object
$Server7 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value "Apollo-7"
$arrServ7Services = @("Web Processing Manager", "Service Host Manager") 
$Server7 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Services -value 
$arrServ7Services


$Server8 = New-Object System.Object
$Server8 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value "Apollo-8"
$arrServ8Services = @("elasticsearch-service-x64")
$Server8 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Services -value 
$arrServ8Services



#Create an object to represent the entire Server environment
$ServerEnvironment = New-Object System.Object
$ServerEnvironment | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Machines -value 
@($Server1, $Server2, $Server3, $Server4, $Server5, $Server6, $Server7, 
$Server8)


#Iterate through each machine in the environment and stop the services.
for ($x = $ServerEnvironment.Machines.Length-1; $x -gt -1; $x--) {
Write-Host " "
Write-Host " "
Write-Host "Machine:" $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Name
Write-Host "No. of Services we are monitoring:" 
$ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Services.Length

#iterate through services 
for ($c = 0; $c -lt $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Services.Length; $c++) {
   $_s = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Name - 
Credential $Credential -Command{param($SERV) Get-Service -Name $SERV} - 
ArgumentList $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Services[$c]
Write-Host $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Services[$c]  $_s.Status 
$_s.StartType

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Name - 
Credential $Credential -Command{param($SERV) Stop-Service -Name $SERV} - 
ArgumentList $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Services[$c]   
}
 }


#Iterate through each machine in the environment.  Here we are starting the 
services.
for ($x = 0; $x -lt $ServerEnvironment.Machines.Length; $x++) {

Write-Host " "
Write-Host " "

Write-Host "Machine:" $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Name
Write-Host "No. of Services we are monitoring:" 
$ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Services.Length

#iterate through service 
for ($c = 0; $c -lt $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Services.Length; $c++) {
$_s = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Name - 
Credential $Credential -Command{param($SERV) Get-Service -Name $SERV} -ArgumentList $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Services[$c]
Write-Host $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Services[$c]  $_s.Status $_s.StartType

 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Name - 
 Credential $Credential -Command{param($SERV) Start-Service -Name $SERV} - 
 ArgumentList $ServerEnvironment.Machines[$x].Services[$c]

}

  }


 Write-Host "Done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you build a coplicated structure with separate $server variables. You have a list of server names with associated services.

That's a simple list that could be contained in a csv file. If read into a variable object you could iterate through the list without the need of an index.

BTW proper indenting helps reading the code.
There are several unintended line breaks.

```
#Create a credential to be used on remote machines
$User = "MyDomain\myusername"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -asplaintext -force
$Credential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $Password

$ServerServices = @"
"Name","Services"
"Apollo-1","MSSQLSERVER,QueueManager"
"Apollo-2","Analytics Engine,MSSQLSERVER"
"Apollo-3","EDDS Agent Manager,MSSQLSERVER,Secret Store "
"Apollo-4","Service Host Manager,MSSQLSERVER,Service Bus "
"Apollo-5","MSSQLSERVER"
"Apollo-6","Web Processing Manager,Service Host Manager "
"Apollo-7","Web Processing Manager,Service Host Manager "
"Apollo-8","elasticsearch-service-x64"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv


#Iterate through each machine in the environment and stop the services.

ForEach ($Server in $ServerServices){
    $Services = $Server.Services -split ','
    Write-Host " "
    Write-Host " "
    Write-Host "Machine:" $Server.Name
    Write-Host ("No. of Services we are monitoring: {0}" -f $Services.Length)

    #iterate through services 
    ForEach ($Service in $Services) {
        Write-Host ("Proceesing service: {0} on server:{1}" -f $Service,$Server.Name)
    #    $_s = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server.Name -Credential $Credential -Command {
    #        param($SERV) Get-Service -Name $SERV} -ArgumentList $Service
    #    }
#...
    }
}

#Iterate through each machine in the environment.  Here we are starting the 

# same as above

Write-Host "Done"
```

Sample output:

```
Machine: Apollo-1
No. of Services we are monitoring: 2
Proceesing service: MSSQLSERVER on server:Apollo-1
Proceesing service: QueueManager on server:Apollo-1


Machine: Apollo-2
No. of Services we are monitoring: 2
Proceesing service: Analytics Engine on server:Apollo-2
Proceesing service: MSSQLSERVER on server:Apollo-2

...snip...
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on formatting.  I'll improve upon that in the future.  I guess the reason I went with objects is for two reasons.  1) PowerShell does a pretty good job of displaying objects to the console screen.  2) I guess I was thinking about potential future use and adding other properties and methods if need be.